# How do I make sure I get back cookies with Node.js' Request module?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I've been following a friend's python code in order to try and log into a site called mangadex, so that I could get the login token out of it. But whenever I run the script and call the login function, all I get out of it is a null value. If I try logging the cookies from inside the post request (console.log(sessionID)), I do actually end up getting the cookies, which is quite puzzling to me. What am I doing wrong here?

Also, I'd appreciate it if anyone could point out pointless things I'm doing in the code that I can just chop away at.

```
class MAuth {
    constructor(serverType) {
        this.serverType = serverType;
        this.j = request.jar();
    }

    async login(username, password) {
        var sessionID = null;

        const options = {
            uri: `https://mangadex.org/ajax/actions.ajax.php?function=login`,
            jar: this.j,
            headers: {
                'user-agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/75.0.3770.100 Safari/537.36',
                'content-type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded', 
            },
            form: {
                'login_username': username,
                'login_password': password,
                'remember_me': 0,
            }
        };
        request
            .post(options)
            .on('response', function(response) {
                sessionID = options.jar.getCookies(options.uri);
            }).on('error', function(err) {
                console.log("error: " + err);
            });
        return sessionID;
    }
}
```

I'm expecting to see something a little bit like this:

```
[ Cookie="__cfduid=blahblahblah; Expires=Tue, 07 Jul 2020 02:25:57 GMT; Domain=mangadex.org; Path=/; HttpOnly; hostOnly=false; aAge=1ms; cAge=14ms" ]
```